# where does the `scalr` variable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

Well I have for the past three days tried to sort this out to no avail, looked at dozens of questions and answers.
Here is the offending code.  I have marked where it falls over with >> this is about the 4th line up from the bottom.
The error message is: Must declare a scalar variable, the result needed is to get the number of records with that date of the procedure being carried out by a specific surgeon.

```
protected void ItemUpdated_refreshSQLDS1(object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        strCmd = "SELECT ScheduledSurgeryID, PatientSurgeryID, " +
           "Hospital, SurgeryDate, Surgeon, Anaesthetist, Patient, " +
           "Gender, DateofBirth, NHINumber, Address, HomePh, Mobile, " +
           "WorkPh, Email, DayStay, NightsHosp, OperationOrder, " +
           "AdmitTime, SurgeryTime, ARTPDescription, " +
           "PrimaryProcedure, ACCCode, MBSECode, Side, ClaimNumber, " +
           "PolicyNumber, Insurer, OpTime, SurgeonID, MedicalAlert, " +
           "AnaestheticType, ACCPurchaseOrder, PriorApproval, " +
           "EquipmentRequired, HospitalID, SurgeonFee, PatientFileNo FROM vSurgeryList " +
           "WHERE PatientSurgeryID = '" + Session["sid"] + "'";

      
        SqlDataSource1.DataSourceMode = SqlDataSourceMode.DataSet;
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = strConnStr;
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = strCmd;
        FormView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        FormView1.DataBind();

        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-NZ");

        DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
        DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(args);
        DataTable dt = view.ToTable();

        var st = dt.Rows[0] 
        ["SurgeryDate"].ToString().PadRight(10).Substring(0, 10);
        DateTime surgdate = Convert.ToDateTime(st,ci);

        string thedate = surgdate.ToShortDateString();
    
        this.Session["surgeryDate"] = dt.Rows[0]["SurgeryDate"];
        
        MessageBox.Show(thedate);

        strCmd = "SELECT vSurgeryList.ScheduledSurgeryID " +
                ",vSurgeryList.SurgeryDate "+
                ",tblSurgeons.SurgeonID "+
                "FROM dbo.vSurgeryList " +
                "INNER JOIN dbo.tblSurgeons ON vSurgeryList.Surgeon = 
                   tblSurgeons.Surgeon "+
                "WHERE tblSurgeons.SurgeonID = '" + 
                 Session["CurrentSurgeonID"] + "' "
                 + "AND vSurgeryList.SurgeryDate = @date";

        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd);
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();

        param1.ParameterName = "@date";
        param1.Value = thedate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

        ds = data.ReturnDataSet(strCmd, param1.ParameterName, param1.Value);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        int rc = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        SqlDataSource2.DataSourceMode = SqlDataSourceMode.DataSet;
        SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = strConnStr;
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = strCmd;
        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
       thedate;

         args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
        >>            view = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(args);
        dt = view.ToTable();
         rc = dt.Rows.Count;

    }
```

Comment: `string thedate = surgdate.ToShortDateString();` Don't do that - you should be passing in a `DateTime` not a `string`.

Comment: `SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = strCmd;` should that be `SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = cmd;`?

Comment: strCmd is the select from string that is passed to the data access layer along with the cmd  stuff.  The string thedate is made from a gridview field that is held in a date field in the database but when it is retrieved it comes out with minutes yet the field is not a datetime field.  I understand that parameters get round the date format problems.  Thats the trouble with us old newbies.

Comment: *`"WHERE PatientSurgeryID = '" + Session["sid"] + "`'* That's a recipe for trouble, even if the `Session["sid"]` doesn't come from the user. Use parameters. Always.

Comment: Convert the Session object(s) to strings. e.g.   Session["sid"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, it all seemed to revolve round date format, when I changed the date format from "dd/MM/yyyy" to "yyyyMMdd" it worked perfectly.

Comment: No, you should use surgdate as the value of the parameter